# Dell Developer Edition Wifi wont connect 802.1x

Tags: wireless, dell

I just picked up a Dell DEv edition precision laptop with Intel wifi. It connects to some wpa2 personal networks but wont connect to my work wifi. I have 14.04 and I updated all of the software - as you can see from the logs the system gets to authentication and succeeds but then some gtk warning comes up and it deauthenticates for "NO REASON"

```
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim NetworkManager[848]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (SSID='FEVMA' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.115142] wlan0: authenticate with 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim NetworkManager[848]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.127720] wlan0: send auth to 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (try 1/3)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (SSID='FEVMA' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.242361] wlan0: send auth to 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (try 2/3)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.243486] wlan0: authenticated
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.243869] wlan0: associate with 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (try 1/3)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.246799] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=120)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: Associated with 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim NetworkManager[848]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associated
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.248127] wlan0: associated
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: WPA: Failed to set GTK to the driver (alg=2 keylen=32 keyidx=1)
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim wpa_supplicant[14896]: wlan0: RSN: Failed to configure GTK
Mar 30 12:59:47 Dovakim kernel: [10229.274353] wlan0: deauthenticating from 04:da:d2:a6:ab:05 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone messing with this problem it looks like Dell is working on it (driver issue).

Here is the thread with the temporary work around

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19678137?pi22229=1